# ActionScript game window coordinates set/get

Tags: actionscript-3, coordinates, sprite

I want to write my first game on ActionScrpit 3. Now for my game I need a game window and I want to have a rectangle drawn in the game window so that its Y coordinate was 50px less than the window size is. My game window should extend Sprite. How can I do this.

In other words my question is how to set and get game window coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Window size would be stage size - `stage.stageWidth` and `stage.stageHeight`, every `DisplayObject` that is added to the display list has a public property stage.

For drawing a rectangle, use Sprite's graphics

```
sprite.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000);
sprite.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
sprite.graphics.endFill();
```

look up the functions at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html